# What is the use of space in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell program as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1
b=2
c=`expr $a+$b`      
echo $c
```

The output is `1+2`.

But if I change

```
c=`expr $a+$b\`
```

to

```
c=`expr $a + $b`
```

The output is going to be 3.

I wonder what is the use of space here.

Comment: Grossly speaking, spaces are separating arguments to programs or shell builtins. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Unless you have to support very old `/bin/sh` (like on Solaris 10), you can do `c=$((a + b))` instead of invoking `expr`. This is faster and avoids various special cases (such as the one you're asking about and one where `expr` treats an initial negative number as an option).

Answer (score 2):

`expr` is a shell command expecting arguments of two types: operands (the "numbers") and operators (+, -, *, etc.). In your case, you want to pass three arguments to `expr`, which are $a, +, and $b. The dollar sign values are expanded into their actual values of 1 and 2 by your shell, and not by `expr`. So, when you do `expr $a + $b`, the actual shell command is `expr 1 + 2`, which gives you 3.

When you don't put spaces in, what gets executed is `expr 1+2`. The `expr` program doesn't know what to do with `1+2` as its sole argument, and thus just echoes it back untouched.